# Min(id) > 3 sql condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried to write the following query:

```
DELETE FROM tbl HAVING id > MIN(id) + 3;
```

But fot the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "HAVING"
```

Is it ever possible to write such a query with `having` and avoid writing a sub select returning `min(id)`?

Comment: `DELETE FROM tbl where id > (select MIN(id)+3 from tbl) ;`

Comment: Of course it's not possible : how would PG guess on what selection of rows it's supposed to aggregate ?

Comment: A way could be to write a procedure doing it. This can include having and avoiding a sub-select, but would be a real waste of resources.

Comment: "*Is it ever possible to write such a query with having*" - no. The `DELETE` statement does not allow the use of a `having` (or a `group by`). "*and avoid writing a sub-select*" - another no (a consequence of the first no)

Answer (score 3):

Use a sub-query for the min value:

```
DELETE FROM tbl where id > (select MIN(id) from tbl) + 3;
```

(I.e. sub-select is needed!)

Comment: Well... I think becuase It's not answering the question. But without adding more complexity it would be a no.